# Programmatically remove the header of UITableView and automatically resizes the content to fill in the removed area

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, interface-builder

I have added a `UIButton` in the header section of the `UITableView` via the interface builder and would like to remove the access to the button in certain cases. I have tried to use the `.hidden = TRUE` property but it just hides the button from the view, leaving a white space behind. How do I programmatically remove the header of `UITableView` and have the table's content automatically resizes to fill in the removed header area?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you want to remove the table's header view, just set the myTable.tableHeaderView property to nil.  If what you have is actually a section header, then you need to return nil from the viewForHeaderInSection method and call [myTableView reloadData]

Comment: that did the trick! thanks! (i'll vote up when i have more rep points, cheers!)

Comment: Would be helpful in the OP could update the title of question to make it it clear that he is talking about section headers and not the tableView header.

Comment: @wuf810, but he's not talking about section headers.  He stated clearly that  he added the UIButton to the header section of the UITableView.  Bogatyr generously answered the question for both cases, though.

Comment: @Harris yeh and like I said he should update the "Title" of the question to reflect (not just rely on the description). Otherwise it makes searching a mockery.

Comment: @wuf810, what do you think the title should be?

Comment: @Sumit *shrug*, the answer is nearly 6 years old and about 7 iOS versions ago.  Not too surprising.

Comment: Thank you very much! It still works perfectly fine on iOS 11.

Answer (score 20):

You could also do:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.0;
}
```

This seems to work for my (single) section header and avoids the need for `reloadData`.

Note that:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

is still called, but its return value seems to be ignored.

Comment: Thanks @MartinStanley it worked just fine and i didn't need to call the `reloadData` method.

Comment: If the header is currently on screen, I'm doubtful that not calling `reloadData` will change anything even if you conditionally return 0 from heightForHeaderInSection, because the table doesn't need to check the header until it goes off-screen and comes back on-screen again.   Callilng `reloadData` is the only way to guarantee the removal of the section header in all cases.

Comment: setting it to 0 still wastes resources. return nil from viewHeader is better than just hiding the table.

Comment: This looks like the right answer if you have to disable the header forcefuly

Answer (score 0):

I created a boolean property called `removeHeader` and then when ever I want to remove my header I call:

```
func removeSectionHeader() {
        removeHeader = true
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Then when my tableView reloads it will call this tableView delegate method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if removeHeader {
            return 0.0
        } else {
            let height = self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight
            return height
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your tableView has a grouped style, in that case a white space appears at the top of the table. Change the style to plain and that blank space will be removed.
[image]