# Only show the rows in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have a UITableView and for the life of me I can't hide the header and all the footer. I have tried multiple methods posted on here.

I want to hide the white space on top and bottom of the populated rows.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.


//Disable Scrolling in TableView
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

//Get rid of unpopulated rows
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];

//Hide UITableViewHeader
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] init];


//Populate Table with Test Data
[self testTableView];

}
```

[image]

Comment: The chosen answer here does the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164291/programmatically-remove-the-header-of-uitableview-and-automatically-resizes-the

Comment: Are you sure that whitespace at the top and bottom is header and footer? You table might be sizing down to what its looking like!

Comment: The Yellow is the View, the white is the TableView and the Green are the rows. Can you explain further?

Comment: I'm going to make the assumption that you used Interface Builder and the connected the view to it rather than problematically created the UITableView. If this is the case then did you verify that your View in interface builder is set to 100% of the screen size and that your table element is also set to 100% of the view size? It may sound like a stupid question but think of all the compilation errors to lack of semi-colon or a typo.

Comment: Why are you setting the header and footer views to new UIView instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `UITableView`'s layout frame is not getting properly adjusted. Since I am not sure if you are using autolayout constraints or autozingmask therefore please try adding following code to your view controller to force your table to size according to the screen.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    self.tableView.frame = self.view.frame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the tableviewHeader to nil or if you want to hide section headers just return nil from viewForHeaderInSection and reload the tableData.

Comment: I changed to self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil; in viewDidLoad and it didn't work :(

Comment: Have you tried returning nil from viewForHeaderInSection? `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { return nil; }`