# how to remove header and footer from a table view in iOS Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am unable to remove the header and footer from the grouped table view. I am using Xcode 6.1 and my code is as follows.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    arr=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Facebook",@"Twitter",@"Linkedin", @"Google+",@"App.net", nil];
    imgView=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"fb.png",@"tw.png",@"ln.png",@"em.png", @"em.png", nil];

    self.tableView.layer.borderWidth=1.0;

    self.tableView.tableFooterView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

}
```

Comment: [Here is the answer from stackoverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5164520/3102255

Comment: Share your screen shot, there is no header and footer assigned as default. What exactly you want to remove?

Comment: According your code you create them whereas question asks how to delete...

Answer (score 6):

Just set them to nil

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
self.tableView.tableFooterView = nil;
```

Answer (score 5):

For future visitors returning zero height with heightForHeaderInSection will also get the same results.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift, use this

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView()