# How to hide the headers of my UITableViews sections programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want the headers and footers for my UITableView's sections to be hidden, and I'm currently setting them up like so:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.0;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return nil;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return nil;
}
```

As you can see in the screenshot, this has successfully hidden the footers, but not the headers (shown in gray). What's missing?

[image]

Comment: Is this a dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164291/programmatically-remove-the-header-of-uitableview-and-automatically-resizes-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `heightForHeaderInSection` doesn't work with 0. Try this one:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.0001f;
}
```

Comment: Bingo, thank you! Strange that 0 doesn't work but that number does.